# Objective-C, constantly run method whilst Mac OS X application is running

Tags: objective-c, xcode, itunes, scripting-bridge

i'm currently writing an application in Objective-C which displays the artist name of the song currently being played in iTunes, however i want the artist name to update when the song changes.

This is the method i have so far which gets the artist name and sets a NSTextField to display the artist name.

```
 - (void)updateArtistName {
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
     NSString *artistNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[iTunes currentTrack] artist]];
     [artistName setStringValue:artistNameString];}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks, Sami.

Comment: uh..is there a question here? no question marks or question words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is: NSDistributedNotificationCenter.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html

To figure out which notifications Itunes is sending most people suggest using: https://github.com/kballard/NotificationWatcher

Comment: Does iTunes post a distributed notification when the song changes?

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't remember the notification name, though.

Comment: From What I can tell from NotificationWatcher is Itunes will send a Distributed Notification com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo